# I am broken: post-undelete reputation issues

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, accepted-answer, deleted-accounts

Specifically FAO Tim Post I guess, but this is probably going to relate to any StackExchange account that has previously been deleted and then put back together by the kind people at StackExchange.

I appear to be the victim of an issue which has given me the acceptance bonus for all questions that I asked which I then subsequently self answered. Examples of some of these questions are as follows;

[Where can I learn to fly in Pandaria?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/85806/52800)

[Where have the PvP vendors gone?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/86622/52800)

In both of the above instances, I have already unaccepted and re-accepted my answer, which subtracted -15 reputation as an "unaccepted" entry in my reputation list, and then added +0 for the new accept, which is the way the system is supposed to work.

Since I have a reasonable number of self-answered content, there will be more. By my reckoning it's about ~1k reputation (based on the reputation I had before I left, subtracting the reputation I've lost due to post edits and low-reputation tag wiki submissions not being re-associated with my account). Obviously I'd rather not lose it ;) - but in the interest of not gaming the system I figured it needs reporting and correcting.

The two above questions and the reputation changes caused by unaccepting and reaccepting the questions [can be seen on my reputation list for the 22nd and 23rd of September 2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/52800/kalina?tab=reputation).

Comment: We're having a look at this, thanks for taking the time to write this up.

Comment: Upvoted for being the rare kind of citizen who appears to be complaining about having *more* rep than they should.

Comment: @TimPost thanks a lot - I know you've already put a significant amount of time into bringing me back in the first place! Sorry for taking up more of your time with my account!

Comment: @Jaydles certainly not complaining about having more reputation than I should, I'd rather be honest about it than hide the fact though that's for sure!

Comment: Technically, this is a post-Post post undelete.

Comment: I see what you did there!

Comment: @Flyk, just to be clear, that's my way of saying thanks - keep up the awesome work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an artifact of how we move around accepted votes when a user is deleted (to keep track of what's accepted still).  The remapping of content doesn't really account for this (and still doesn't).  I'll look into it handling it as part of the process soon as time allows.

For now I've fixed up all your posts in the database and kicked off a recalc at the same time.  Your reputation and votes should be correct.