# keep reputation after deleting my account

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts

If I delete my account for let's say gaming.stackexchange.com and then later I make a new account(for gaming.stackexchange.com).

Both the old and the new account would be created with facebook.

Will I have the reputation I had before(I deleted my account) or is my reputation reset?

Comment: I would assume that your reputation would be reset.

Comment: No you will not have it back. Account deletion is not reversible.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202715/when-an-account-is-deleted-is-it-removed-from-the-database?rq=1

Comment: Of course you won't get your reputation back. The posts are no longer linked to the account. If you request deletion, what exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Oded might be worth an answer, surprisingly didn't find exact dupe for this. :)

Comment: @Oded Maybe an account could have been put on "Inactive".

Comment: @Damek there's no such thing as "Inactive" status.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, lets think about this. Someone requests their account be deleted.

What needs to happen in order for that request to be accomplished, while retaining all of the content (licensed as cc-by-sa) from that user?

The content needs to be anonymized and the user row removed from the database. Now, the act of anonymizing the content means **there is no way to correlate it to the user**.

If the same person creates a new account, even with the same credentials, the link to all of their content has been lost and cannot be put back. And since that content is what reputation is based on, then no, a newly created account would not have any reputation associated with it.

Frankly, I don't know why anyone would expect getting **anything** back after requesting deletion. You know - because deleting stuff means it is no longer there? That's what the word means.

Comment: Great answer, sadly can't vote up.

Comment: @Damek - Here you go...

Comment: Maybe @Damek thinks that account deletion is like file deletion in Windows, sending it to a Recycle Bin and being able to Restore at will.

Comment: @Shadow Oh the accursed recycle bin. I always forget to empty that. The real one as well as the virtual one...