# I am broken: post-undelete bounty issues

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, deleted-accounts

Related: [I am broken: post-undelete reputation issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197973/i-am-broken-post-undelete-reputation-issues)

It appears that as a result of the account undeletion process, the bounties that I have handed out and been awarded are not correctly applied against my profile. This is best visible by looking at my [Arqade profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/52800/kalina?tab=bounties) which only shows bounty activity applied since my account was undeleted.

At best guess, these are the bounties that are missing:

- [Will Split trigger Prodigy for each Magic Missile fired?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71928/will-split-trigger-prodigy-for-each-magic-missile-fired/73165#73165)
- [Is it reasonable to expect to retrieve my initial investment for buying Diablo 3 via the Real Money Auction house?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66536/is-it-reasonable-to-expect-to-retrieve-my-initial-investment-for-buying-diablo-3/74442#74442)
- [Why does this item have a legend? Are there others like it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69712/why-does-this-item-have-a-legend-are-there-others-like-it/72389#72389)
- [Which bosses have an enrage timer and what are their effects?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70637/which-bosses-have-an-enrage-timer-and-what-are-their-effects/72390#72390)
- [How is the Quality Well in Old Tristram Unlocked?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69875/how-is-the-quality-well-in-old-tristram-unlocked/72391#72391)
- [Are Nachos Nutritious and/or Tasty?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76608/are-nachos-nutritious-and-or-tasty/79286#79286)
- [What is the maximum distance that Patriot missile launchers can communicate over?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97292/what-is-the-maximum-distance-that-patriot-missile-launchers-can-communicate-over)
- [What's the maximum inventory size?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76283/whats-the-maximum-inventory-size/79308#79308)
- [Once you build a University, can the high school and community college be safely closed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107972/once-you-build-a-university-can-the-high-school-and-community-college-be-safely/108926#108926)

Would it be possible for somebody at Stack Exchange to have a look at this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Well, yes, we can look, but no - there's not much we can do.

Deletion is a pretty permanent thing, that's why we go out of our way to clearly explain to folks that have more than a trivial number of contributions that it's pretty much an irreversible process before processing such requests.

We *can*, sometimes, at our discretion, remap someone's previous posts to a new account. That is a very manual process, we can't always do it, and we're quite reluctant to try barring extenuating circumstances. But that's the extent of what we can do - the following things are, well, gone:

- Votes you've cast
- Bounties you've given or been awarded
- Badges coming from anything but the score and views of your posts
- Flags & flag history

... other stuff I'm probably forgetting. Given how our system currently works, delete removes a *lot* of stuff in a way that it can't be easily found later.

We don't really have an 'undeletion' process to speak of, it really is just one of us fishing to find your previous contributions and then bolting them back on.

Comment: No worries, I had made assumptions regarding stuff like votes, badges, review queue history and flags but figured that since I can easily see the bounties in the data explorer that these might be fixable. Thanks for the response!